# What is the difference between functions nndist and kNNdist?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, cluster-analysis, nearest-neighbor

I am currently trying to implement the DBSCAN algorithm with R to find outliers in my data. In order to initialize parameters (epsilon especially), I have to plot the ascending sorted sequence of distances to the kth neighbour (I chose `k = 3`) in my sample and see  where is the elbow to select the correct value for epsilon.

As I said I am using the R statistical language and I have found two different function that calculate the distance to the kth neighbour `nndist()` and `kNNdist()`. If I have understood well by default it uses the Euclidean distance. However in my data, the functions do not display the same results. To illustrate my issue, I implement the two functions on the famous `iris` dataset and you can see that the results are quite different:

```
data(iris)
iris <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])

distance_third_neighbour_iris = iris %>% nndist(k = 3)

as.vector(quantile(distance_third_neighbour_iris, probs = 0.99))
### gives 0.68

distance_third_neighbour_iris = iris %>% kNNdist(k = 3)

as.vector(quantile(distance_third_neighbour_iris, probs = 0.99))
### gives 0.81
```

Obviously, both functions seem to not use the same distance by default or method to calculate.

Comment: Do *not* use DBSCAN to find outliers. Noise is not the same as outliers. It's just points that are not frequent enough to be a cluster. Use a real outlier detection algorithm instead. Try some of the algorithms in ELKI, for example.

Comment: As a side benefit, you don't have to choose epsilon anymore. Most methods only have one parameter, corresponding to minpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here:

1. When `nndist` takes a matrix as an input, it assumes that it is only two-dimensional. In order to accept the four columns of the `iris` dataset as four-dimensional points and trigger the multidimensional version of `nndist` – which is `nndist.ppx` – you first need to transform `iris` to `ppx` points like this: `ppx(iris)`
2. Even after taking care of 1., the results would still be different. That is because `kNNdist` does not produce just the distance to the k=3 neighbor, but a dataframe which contains a column for all distances up to k=3 (that is, k=1, k=2, and k=3). Therefore, when you try to get the value only for k=3 and you want to compare it to the result from `nndist`, you should use only the third column, like this: `distance_third_neighbour_iris_knndist[,3]`

Your code modified, then, should be:

```
library(dbscan)
library(spatstat)

data(iris)
iris <- as.matrix(iris[,1:4])

distance_third_neighbour_iris_nndist = ppx(iris) %>% nndist(k = 3)

as.vector(quantile(distance_third_neighbour_iris_nndist, probs = 0.99))
### gives 0.8776718

distance_third_neighbour_iris_knndist = iris %>% kNNdist(k = 3)

as.vector(quantile(distance_third_neighbour_iris_knndist[,3], probs = 0.99))
### gives 0.8776718
```

Comment: May I suggest you update your answer to be reproducible? I get `Error in ppx(iris) %>% nndist(k = 3) : could not find function "%>%"`. Probably you want to call `library(magrittr)` first. Also you can get the first three nn-distances with `nndist` using argument `k = 1:3`.

Comment: Is there a function in python similar to these in R: kNNdist, nndist ?